# Skip objects that do not exist (filter) React-Native

Tags: javascript, json, loops, react-native, object

I have a situation where I am looping through an array of objects. Lets say whenever there are more then 2 objects, if the first object doesnt exist how to skip that and continue to the next one?

Here is the loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < this.myInputFields.myTextFields.length; i++) {

        if (!this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i] || this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i] == null || this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i] === '') {
           //go to next
        }

        if (this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key) {
             data[this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key] = this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues;
        }

    }
```

Here is the printed array when the first object doesnt exist:

```
    [ ,
   { type: 'textfield',
     placeholderText: 'Enter your number',
     title: '*number',
     key: 'signedByNumber',
   inputType: 'numbers',
    inputValues: '553' } ]
```

As you can see, before that object there is a comma and a space before the comma, so I dont know how to skip that space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code will allow you to skip the elements whose is empty.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.myInputFields.myTextFields.length; i += 1) {
  if (this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i]) {
    // print valid element if you want or do whatever you want
    data[this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key] = this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues;
  }
}
```

More efficient way is

```
let array = this.myInputFields.myTextFields.filter(item => item !== undefined); // you can eliminate all undefined elements with filter method

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  data[array[i].key] = array[i].inputValues;
}
```

Comment: If I could give you more then 1 upvote I would do it! Thanks a million time, I was trying to fix this bug the whole day.

Comment: Btw I am using the second approach.

Comment: one more question, any idea how to check if any of the key values contain '*' ? I cant specify which key because they are dynamic but I need to check for all keys one-by-one if any of them contains that sign.

Comment: You can use `let newarray = arr.filter(item => item.key.includes('*'));`. After that `newarray` only includes elements which 'key' attribute has '*' value.

Comment: then I should write a for loop and call newArray?

Comment: Yes. Also you can check simply how much element that includes '*' via `console.log('length: ', arr.filter(item => item.key.includes('*')).length);`.

Comment: I did this but its not working:  for (let i = 0; i < newarray.length; i += 1) {

            Alert.alert('There is a required field')

        }

Comment: Well.. if the alert is not triggered then newarray has no element. Just control your approach again, there must be logical problem in somewhere.

Comment: I can see where the problem is, 'item.key.filter()' the 'key' is actually the name of a key in the objects. So what can I do in this case?

Comment: Why you use 'item.key.filter()'? You should show me more of your code. I do not understand exactly what you want to do with this code.

Comment: sorry I meant item.key.includes()

Comment: Yes, it is name of 'key' attribute in element. Which key do you want to get?

Comment: As I said before I cant specify which one because they change dynamically so that '*' could be anywhere. And each object contains multiple keys with values.

Comment: Any idea Firats?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194922/discussion-between-firats-and-bimixbimix).